# How can I get my new iteration to show in Team Foundation Server 2010's reporting services report criteria?

Tags: tfs

I created the iteration "File List Creator 2.0.0.0" on my team foundation server on 11/23/2012.  I then created a bunch of tasks under it and finished them over the following week.  It is now 11/30/2012.  Below is an image of my iteration tree:

[image]

I went into the Team Foundation Server reporting services to look at my burndown chart and my new iteration that I made a week ago doesn't show in the list:

[image]

I even went onto the server and reran the reporting analysis service and the warehouse analysis service through the TFS web services.  Its still not showing.  So how do I get it to update?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the analysis DB was not update properly rebuilt for some reason.
What I would suggest if a full rebuild through the web service as such:

1) The easiest way is to go onto the server and browse to the web service: `http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx`

2) Click "ProcessWarehouse".

[image: no. 2]

3) For the parameter "collectionName" write "DefaulCollection" (or the name of your collection), and click "Invoke".

[image: no. 3]

4) This is what you're supposed to see:

[image: no. 4]

5) Go Back to: `http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asm`x and click "ProcessAnalysisDatabase".

[image: no. 5]

6) For the parameter "processingType:" write "Full" and click "Invoke".

[image: no. 6]

7) This is what you're supposed to see:

[image: no. 7]

Answer (score 0):

One more option, is all others are exhausted, is to "reprocess" the Analysis DB directly:

[image]